# Is there a difference in pronunciation between "ist" and "isst"?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

Is there a difference in pronunciation between "ist" -*be (3p. sing)* and "isst" -*eat (3p. sing)*?

---

EDIT: I posted the second part as an [independent question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/double-consonants-in-german)

Comment: Der Junge isst ein Kind.... Is he a cannibal?

Comment: "Der Junge isst ein Kind", yes if you write it like this then he is a cannibal.

Comment: What is diferent in words"Das Bäer isst eine Katze" (Bear eats Cat) and "Das Bäer ist eine Katze" (Bear is Cat ) How we non speaking Germans to understand that two diferents ?

Comment: @user8712: Well, apart from the fact that it is "*der* Bär", for animals the correct verb is "fressen", therefore "Der Bär frisst eine Katze" vs. "Der Bär ist eine Katze". And of course generally it should be clear from context what it meant (for example, there are very few contexts where a bear is a cat).

Comment: The same thing happens if you say: Du hast Eier / Du hasst Eier. It's only the context to decide, if you *have* eggs or if you *hate* eggs. German is sometimes funny. At the first time, in school, when I heard "Peter isst eine Banane" I laughed very loud! Of course I thought, that there is banana called Peter, and well, "Peter is a banana".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### No.

According to **wiktionary.org** (and my experience) the pronunciation is the same for "**ist**" and "**isst**":

> ist: [[ɪst]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ist)
> isst: [[ɪst]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/isst)

Some people will argue that you emphasize the "s" in "isst", but in fact the emphasis is on the "i" both times according to the **Duden**.

> ['ist](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ist)
> ['isst](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/isst)

Comment: One thing worth noting is that in "ist" the t tends to be dropped  in informal spoken language ("Er is' 'ne Gurke."). That does not happen with "isst" ("Er isst 'ne Gurke.").

Comment: @elena: I was about to start an answer and saw your great comment. The difference you mention is true for all regional dialects, be it Hamburg or Zwiesel.

Comment: From what you say one could think that you could also write `i'st`, if the `s` was emphasized, but this is not true, for sure [not in IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Suprasegmentals), where the apostrophe marks the stressed _syllable_

Comment: Note that there are even dialects out there (Swabian, Schwäbisch) which distinguish between *er isch* und *er issd*, making the difference even clearer.

Answer (score 8):

They sound exactly the same, they just are spelled differently

> Er isst einen [Hamburger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger).
>
> Er ist ein [Hamburger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg).

They are 2 different verbs that have 2 different meanings, that when conjugated for Er/Sie/Es sound exactly the same

Comment: I pronounce "Hamburger" (food) as "Hämbörger" to avoid problems. Don't want anybody to think, I am a cannibal.

Comment: They don't sound the same.

Comment: @Robert Care to expand on that?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist See The_Fritz' answer. "ist" and "isst" are pronounced differently, even though a non-native speaker may not easily catch the difference, and not only when you want to emphasize.

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, but lots of Germans pronounce "ist" without the "t" at the end.Generally there is absolutely no difference. You can guess the meaning from the context like

> Er ist/isst ein Kind.

Here it is clear that it has to be "ist".

> Er ist/isst eine Suppe.

Now it is "isst", because usually you can't be a soup :D

Answer (score 1):

In "isst", you put more emphasis on the i and the s is a little bit sharper than in "ist".

Comment: You _might_ try this in an ambiguous situation to make clear which of the two words you mean. But in general: No, I can't confirm what you say.

Comment: There really isn't an ambiguous situation that could occur where you could mix the 2 up, `Er isst pizza` when you say this it could sound like `He is pizza` but from context you can tell the sentence means `He eats pizza`

Comment: @John: True, it's hardly ever ambiguous. But sometimes it's even on purpose: [Man ist was man isst](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22man+ist+was+man+isst%22).

Comment: Nein, das stimmt nicht. "ist" und "isst" werden genau gleich ausgesprochen: "Hans ist ein Hamburger, der einen Hamburger isst."

Comment: Ambiguous situation: "er ist schnell" vs. "er isst schnell" — but here, in the first case youd' emphasize as "er ist *schnell*" while in the second case you'd normally say "er *isst* schnell" unless you explicitly want to emphasize "schnell" (OT-Englischfrage: habe ich "betonen" korrekt mit "emphasize" übersetzt?)