# Double consonants in German

Tags: consonant-sounds

Are there double consonants in German that differentiate between words? Like in Italian where for example, "ca**s**a" means *house* and "ca**ss**a" means *box*.

---

This question is related to the question "[Is there a difference in pronunciation between “ist” and “isst”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/is-there-a-differnce-in-pronunciation-between-ist-and-isst)" in which it was originally asked.

Comment: man/Mann --- offen/Ofen

Comment: As far as I understand *minimal pairs* (or *[Minimalpaare](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar)* in German) are only about the phonetics. Therefore, it does not make sense to talk about a **"minimal pair only in writing"**.

Comment: I crossed out this section

Comment: On the other hand, many of the minimal pairs are also cases where the only difference in the spelling is the double consonant.

Comment: More: ist / isst, Rate / Ratte, beten / betten

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, there are double consonants in German that differentiate between words.

   > [Watte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watte) (cotton)
   >
   > [Wate](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wate) (facet)

   You can look through [this list of words with double consonants](http://online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/rechtschreibung_5_7/02_deutsch_uebungen_kurze_vokale/09_uebungen_woerterliste_doppelte_konsonanten.htm) and search for more yourself. Happy hunting!
2. [Minimalpaare](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar) mit Vorkommen an Doppelkonsonanten (vgl. [Vokalquantität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokalquantit%C3%A4t))

   > Bann vs. Bahn
   >   Mitte vs. Miete
   >   Pollen vs. Polen
   >   Busse vs. Buße
   >   bette vs. bete vs. bäte
   >   Hölle vs. Höhle
   >   fülle vs. fühle

   The latter is taken from [Vokalquantität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokalquantit%C3%A4t) at Wikipedia.

Comment: `Maße` und `Masse`

Comment: Besonders schön im Plural: In Maßen vs. in Massen.

Answer (score 4):

There are also a few examples that are homophones:

- Mann/man
- Inn/in

Answer (score 2):

- das – dass
- Wal – Wall
- Hüte – Hütte
- Schal – Schall
- Schrot – Schrott
- Schote – Schotte
- Scharen – Scharren
- Nute – Nutte
- scharen – scharren
- er ist – er isst
- Koma – Komma
- Amen – Ammen
- Halo – Hallo
- wir – wirr
- Raten – Ratten
- Mate – Matte
- Magie – Maggie :-)

Comment: +0.5 for [Maggi](http://www.maggi.de/start/)